# Installing extension from Magento 2 marketplace

Tags: magento-2.1, extensions

I am installing my first Magento 2 extension which I purchased from the Marketplace. Is it necessary to increase the PHP memory limit to 2000M or can I leave it at 768M?

Comment: are you using CLI for installing extension

Comment: I have tried to its take lots of memory you are not able to install extension with 768M

Comment: I am using the component manager for installation.